# FIX sendToTarget taking lot of time in python

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm trying to prepare FIX exec message and then trying to send to the session using this.

```
fix.Session.sendToTarget(fix_message, self._session_id)
```

This method is invoked every time we receive execs from the exchange, we prepare the fix message and then for every message me call this method. This whole task scheduled via crontab. So at some point of time when exchange sends 15000 execs it takes lot of time to `sendToTarget` (around 30 min).

When I restart the whole process it works fine. i.e it takes around 90 secs for this method to return for 15000 execs. Can someone help where the problem is in the first case.

Thanks.

Comment: There could be a bottleneck somewhere, you should create a log and see how the functions are executed and its execution time. Crontabs are also notorious to running without prejudice, you could have previous commands still running and a new crontab gets executed with you ending with multiple instance of the same thing draining CPU resources.

Comment: I have logged everything, and can't figure out why sendtotarget is taking so much time.

Comment: crontab entry invokes it once a day, so i guess draining the cpu should not be problem, can it be because we many times get 0 trades as response in the begining as we start the process quite early and then when we start getting some non zero numbers it has drained cpu? Although we are not calling sendToTarget when we get 0 trades

Comment: @JamesWong what are your views on this?  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesWong, its because of cron. sendToTarget runs slower when run via cron vs non-cron, do you know why this happens?